# Django Raven only logs once to Sentry

Tags: django, sentry, raven

I have set up my logging to go to Sentry in my app. When I run ./manage.py raven test, it works every time. When I call the log in lets say a view, it works once. After that it stops logging at all. There are no errors or output at all.

The weird thing is if remove the logging settings and set the logger as:

```
Logger = logging.getLogger('django.request')
```

It works every time

settings.py

```
LOGGING = {
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': True,
        'root': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'handlers': ['sentry'],
        },
        'formatters': {
                'verbose': {
                        'format': ('%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d '
                                           '%(thread)d %(message)s')
                },
        },
        'handlers': {
                'sentry': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'class': ('raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.'
                                          'SentryHandler'),
                },
        },
        'loggers': {

                'log': {
                        'level': 'DEBUG',
                        'handlers': ['sentry'],
                        'propagate': False
                },
        },
}
```

views.py:

```
import logging
Logger = logging.getLogger('log')

def first_view(request):
    Logger.error('First Error Works', exc_info=True)

def second_view(request):
    Logger.error('Second Error Does Not', exc_info=True)
```

Comment: please show your django project `wsgi.py` file content...